# Strange output when citing and in reference list with biber/ biblatex

Tags: biblatex, biber

when I create (using texlive2014/biber/biblatex/csquotes) a references list or when I simply cite something in the text with commands like this `\parencite[cf.][]{Hunt2007}` or `\textquote[{\cite[2]{Hunt2007}}]{bla bla}`, I get weird outputs, which look like this one from my reference list:

[image: from my references list]

or this one from the text:

[image]

Running the code, I get this error message:

```
INFO - This is Biber 1.9
INFO - Logfile is 'Diplomarbeit.blg'
INFO - Reading 'Diplomarbeit.bcf'
INFO - Using all citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file '/home/sebastian/Documentos/BibTeX library/Diplomarbeit.bib' for section 0
INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
INFO - Found BibTeX data source '/home/sebastian/Documentos/BibTeX library/Diplomarbeit.bib'
WARN - BibTeX subsystem: /tmp/8snweNJr4V/Diplomarbeit.bib_15136.utf8, line 6, warning: 177 characters of junk seen at toplevel
INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
INFO - Sorting list 'nyt' of type 'entry' with scheme 'nyt' and locale 'en-US'
INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'en-US'
INFO - Writing 'Diplomarbeit.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
INFO - Output to Diplomarbeit.bbl
INFO - WARNINGS: 1
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
```

My .bib-file looks like this:

```
Automatically generated by Mendeley Desktop 1.12.3-dev1
Any changes to this file will be lost if it is regenerated by Mendeley.

BibTeX export options can be customized via Options -> BibTeX in Mendeley Desktop

@article{Hunt2007,
abstract = {Rapa Nui (Easter Island) has become a paragon for prehistoric human induced ecological catastrophe and cultural collapse. A popular nar- rative recounts an obsession for monumental statuary that led to the island’s ecological devastation and the collapse of the ancient civilization. Scholars offer this story as a parable of today’s global environmental problems. In this paper, I review new and emerging Rapa Nui evidence, compare ecological and recently acquired palaeo-environmental data from the Hawaiian and other Pacific Islands, and offer some perspectives for the island’s prehistoric ecological transformation and its consequences. The evidence points to a complex historical ecology for the island; one best explained by a synergy of impacts, particularly the devastating effects of introduced rats (Rattus exulans). This perspective questions the simplistic notion of reckless over-exploitation by prehistoric Polynesians and points to the need for additional research.},
author = {Hunt, Terry L.},
doi = {10.1016/j.jas.2006.10.003},
file = {:home/sebastian/Documentos/Biblioteca attiva/Hunt - Rethinking Easter Island's ecological catastrophe.pdf:pdf},
issn = {03054403},
journal = {Journal of Archaeological Science},
keywords = {Collapse,Deforestation,Easter Island,Ecocide,Invasive species,Rapa Nui,Rats,Rattus exulans,collapse,deforestation,easter island,ecocide,for pre-,has become the paragon,invasive species,it,it ain,mark twain,rapa nui,rats,rattus exulans,s,sure that just ain,t know that gets,t so,t what you don,what you know for,you into trouble},
mendeley-tags = {Collapse,Deforestation,Easter Island,Ecocide,Invasive species,Rapa Nui,Rats,Rattus exulans},
month = mar,
number = {3},
pages = {485--502},
title = {{Rethinking Easter Island's ecological catastrophe}},
url = {http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S0305440306002019},
volume = {34},
year = {2007}
}
@misc{Brander,
author = {Brander, James A.},
file = {:home/sebastian/Documentos/Biblioteca attiva/Brander - Easter Island     Resource Depletion and Collapse.pdf:pdf},
title = {{Easter Island: Resource Depletion and Collapse}}
}
```

Does somebody help me to get rid of this strange behaviour?

Comment: What options are you passing to `biblatex`?

Comment: This problem sort of looks like it was caused by a faulty name format or some other dodgy formatting that involves the names. We would need to see the actual document, as the `.bib` and `.blg` file look fine (you don't get an error, just a warning, which is about characters of junk - I suppose that is the automatic blurb Mendeley puts at the beginning of the exported `.bib` file). (When I say, we need to see an actual document, I mean of course we need to see an MWE that shows us how you create your bibliography and what options you are applying to it.)

Comment: Could you create a full MWE for us? Otherwise I think the question - as it stands now - is all but unanswerable.

Comment: I will do so in some days! Thank you for your patience.

Comment: I resolved the issue by simply deactivating all parameters I gave biblatex in the preamble. (Sorry that I did not posted the parameters in the first place!) I found out the problems exist with **indexing=true**. Thank you both for your patience!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem that could not be answered using only the information given in the question and has been resolved by the OP.